# MVC EF layering the code correctly and how to fix navigation naming when updating models from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, tree

I have a two questions.

The first one is about that moment when you go to EDM and update your models from database and it rewrites the old models, losing everything you edited inside them. I read a little about this and it is said that you can create another models and make them also partial and there you may put again the fields so at the next update it won't affect your last changes. How can I do this? I have a separate project for my DAL and the models were generated from database (I have an EDM).

The second question is... But better I give an example. I have a model called `Categories` and another one `CategoriesTranslations`, both of them mapped from my database. Let's say you want to have a list of this categories inside a `DropDownList()` in many views of your website (of your different controllers). The DropDrown will have the value containing the translation which depends on the current language and the keys containing the category ID.
Here is an example of my list:

```
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
var CategoriesTexts = db.Categories.Include(i => i.CategoryTexts).ToList();
foreach (var cat in CategoriesTexts)
{
  var texts = cat.CategoryTexts.Where(w=>w.Language.Format == (string)Session["chosen_language"]).FirstOrDefault();
  listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
  {
    Text = texts == null ? cat.Id.ToString() : texts.Name,
    Value = cat.Id.ToString(),
  });
}
```

Where should I put this code in my website structure (or how can I structure it) to make use of it in most of my Views?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

***For your first question***

There is no need to make partial classes just to fix the naming when you update EF EDMX file. Actually you shouldn't delete the model class from the Edmx when you make update to your database all you need to do is to update the model and it will save your navigation properties names as you made them already.

***For your second Question***

Although I don't agree with you about what you're doing to get the categories to the DropDownList, But you could make this as Extension method for the `IEnumerable<Category>` and put this method in ViewModelExtensions project

e.g.

```
public static IList<SelectListItem> ToDropDownList(this IEnumerable<Category> query)
{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();    
    foreach (var cat in query)
    {
      var texts = cat.CategoryTexts.Where(w=>w.Language.Format == (string)Session["chosen_language"]).FirstOrDefault();
      listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
      {
        Text = texts == null ? cat.Id.ToString() : texts.Name,
        Value = cat.Id.ToString(),
      });
    }
}
```

then just call it in your controllers like this:

```
var list = db.Categories.Include(i => i.CategoryTexts).ToDropDownList();
```

Comment: For the first question. Your updated post is not really what I have asked for. What do you mean by navigation? I was saying that if I update my EDMX from database, if I have set in the past some display names for my models, they will disapear after update.

For the second question. Why don't you agree with that? It's less redundant code. Also can you give me a few more information about ViewModelExtension project?